# How do I create classes that conform to protocols with nested PATs?

Tags: swift, nested, protocols, type-erasure, associated-types

I'm attempting to use type-erasure to create a `Repository` protocol that can be conformed to (similar to Swift's `AnyCollection`). This protocol needs to be wrapped in a type-erased class because it contains a PAT.

However, since this protocol has a nested protocol which also has a PAT, it somewhat complicates things.

- `Keyable` is something that provides a key (which eventually I'd like to ensure is also `Hashable`... one thing at a time).
- `Repository` is my generalized "container" protocol
- `AnyKeyable` type-erased wrapper for `Keyable`
- `AnyRepository` type-erased wrapper for `Repository`

I’ve got a playground snippet that *ALMOST* compiles:

```
protocol Keyable {
    associatedtype KeyType// where KeyType: Hashable
    func key() -> KeyType
}

protocol Repository {
    associatedtype DataType: Keyable
    func all() -> [DataType]
    func get(id: DataType.KeyType) throws -> DataType?
    func create(object: DataType) throws -> Bool
    func update(object: DataType) throws -> Bool
    func delete(object: DataType) throws -> Bool
    func clear() -> Bool
}

final class AnyKeyable<T>: Keyable {
    private let _key: () -> T
    init<U: Keyable>(_ keyable: U) where U.KeyType == T {
        _key = keyable.key
    }

    public func key() -> T {
        return _key()
    }
}

final class AnyRepository<T: Keyable>: Repository {
    private let _all: () -> [T]
    private let _get: (_ id: T.KeyType) throws -> T?
    private let _create: (_ object: T) throws -> Bool
    private let _update: (_ object: T) throws -> Bool
    private let _delete: (_ object: T) throws -> Bool
    private let _clear: () -> Bool

    init<U: Repository>(_ repository: U) where U.DataType == T {
        _get = repository.get
        _create = repository.create
        _delete = repository.delete
        _update = repository.update
        _clear = repository.clear
        _all = repository.all
    }

    func all() -> [T] {
        return _all()
    }

    func get<K: Keyable>(id: K.KeyType) throws -> T? where T.KeyType: Keyable, T.KeyType == K.KeyType {
        let anyKeyable = AnyKeyable(id)
        return try _get(anyKeyable)
    }

    func create(object: T) throws -> Bool {
        return try _create(object)
    }

    func update(object: T) throws -> Bool {
        return try _update(object)
    }

    func delete(object: T) throws -> Bool {
        return try _delete(object)
    }

    func clear() -> Bool {
        return _clear()
    }
}

final class Contact {
    var name: String = ""
    var email: String = ""
}

extension Contact: Keyable {
    public typealias KeyType = String
    public func key() -> String {
        return "im the key"
    }
}

// Just a dummy class to see 
final class ContactRepository: Repository {
    typealias DataType = Contact
    private var someContacts: [Contact] = []

    func all() -> [Contact] {
        return someContacts
    }

    func clear() -> Bool {
        someContacts.removeAll()
        return someContacts.count == 0
    }

    func get(id: Contact.KeyType) throws -> Contact? {
        return nil
    }

    func update(object: Contact) throws -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func create(object: Contact) throws -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func delete(object: Contact) throws -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}

// Testing
let i = AnyRepository<Contact>(ContactRepository())
i.all()
i.clear()
```

The problem with that is the Swift compiler complains that I’m not using `K` in the method signature of `get<K: Keyable>(id: K.KeyType)`... but it looks to me like I definitely am.

My thought is that the compiler is complaining because of the `DataType.KeyType` declaration of `get()` in the protocol, rather than in the `AnyRepository` concrete subclass, but I'm uncertain on how to correct this to provide more context for the compiler.

Is there a better way to structure this to allow me to accomplish this pattern? What about also allowing for the first `associatedtype` in `Keyable` to become `associatedtype KeyType where KeyType: Hashable`?

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: Why are you introducing a new placeholder for `get(id:)` in the type eraser? Surely you just want `func get(id: T.KeyType) throws -> T? { return try _get(id) }`?

Comment: Yup - you're absolutely right. That placeholder was left over from an attempt to get it working with the `Hashable` stuff that was commented out in my post. I never removed it and it was greatly complicating things further than they needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

As Hamish pointed out, there was no need to introduce another generic, `K`. That was complicating things. Cleaning it all up, this now works without the complication of an `AnyKeyable` class:

```
public protocol Keyable {
    associatedtype KeyType where KeyType: Hashable
    func key() -> KeyType
}

public protocol Repository {
    associatedtype DataType: Keyable
    func all() -> [DataType]
    func get(id: DataType.KeyType) throws -> DataType?
    func create(object: DataType) throws
    func create(objects: [DataType]) throws
    func update(object: DataType) throws
    func delete(object: DataType) throws
    func delete(objects: [DataType]) throws
    func clear()
}

public class AnyRepository<T: Keyable>: Repository {
    private let _all: () -> [T]
    private let _get: (_ id: T.KeyType) throws -> T?
    private let _create: (_ object: T) throws -> Void
    private let _createAll: (_ objects: [T]) throws -> Void
    private let _update: (_ object: T) throws -> Void
    private let _delete: (_ object: T) throws -> Void
    private let _deleteAll: (_ objects: [T]) throws -> Void
    private let _clear: () -> Void

    public init<R: Repository>(_ repository: R) where R.DataType == T {
        _get = repository.get
        _create = repository.create
        _createAll = repository.create
        _delete = repository.delete
        _deleteAll = repository.delete
        _update = repository.update
        _clear = repository.clear
        _all = repository.all
    }

    public func all() -> [T] {
        return _all()
    }

    public func get(id: T.KeyType) throws -> T? {
        return try _get(id)
    }

    public func create(object: T) throws {
        return try _create(object)
    }

    public func create(objects: [T]) throws {
        return try _createAll(objects)
    }

    public func update(object: T) throws {
        return try _update(object)
    }

    public func delete(object: T) throws {
        return try _delete(object)
    }

    public func delete(objects: [T]) throws {
        return try _deleteAll(objects)
    }

    public func clear() {
        return _clear()
    }
}
```